# Permanent Static Route to Device

Tags: networking

Does anyone know how to make the following command permanent in Elementary OS?

```
route add -host 192.168.1.1 dev wlp0s20f3
```

This route does exactly what I need, but its not permanent. A reboot of the machine or the network connection will result in it being removed from the IP tables.

I can't seem to find the files that define the routes for this device (wifi adapter - wlp0s20f3).

Comment: Have you tried it with the -p switch? route -p add

Comment: Google is your friend. https://www.networkinghowtos.com/howto/adding-persistent-static-routes-on-ubuntu/

Comment: https://linoxide.com/how-tos/howto-permanently-add-static-route-in-linux/ See the section for Ubuntu. Elementary OS is based in Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi guys - the problem is not how to construct the route, it's that it's temporary. This route works fine. But if i disable/enable the network adapter this route gets removed from the iptables. How can i make this route permanent? (will edit question to make this more clear)

Comment: @Oberleutnant20 I don't see a -p switch listed as an option for ```route```. Is there is link you can share that explains this?

Comment: He means this: route -p add -host 192.168.1.1 dev wlp0s20f3

Comment: @Sysadmin route: invalid option -- 'p'
It's all good though - the accepted answer works well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type in terminal :

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Add at the bottom this:

```
up route add -net 192.168.1.10/24 gw 192.168.1.1 dev wlp0s20f3
```

Where 192.168.1.10 is the IP of your machine which you can check with command:

```
ip a
```

Restart the networking service by typing in terminal:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Comment: Thanks so much Sysadmin! it was the ```up``` at the front that i was missing :)